# Base-point-free linear systems (elementary?) property

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I'm having troubles solving exercise K on page 167 of the book "Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces" of Miranda.

The question is the following one : Let $Q$ be a base-point-free linear system, let $p_1, ...,p_m$ be some points on the Riemann Surface $X$. Show that there is a divisor $D\in Q$ without any $p_i$ in its support.

I tried the following :

Since $Q$ is a base-point-free linear system, it corresponds to some linear system $|\phi|$ associated to some holomorphic map $\phi:X \rightarrow \Bbb P^n$, $x \mapsto [f_0(x): \dots : f_n(x)]$. Here the $f_i$'s denote some meromorphic functions. We have a very clear discription of such a system, namely any divisor in it can be written as $\text{div}(g)+D$, where $D$ is defined as $-\min_i\{\text{div}(f_i)\}$ and $g$ is a linear combination of the $f_i$'s.

Since we're dealing with a base-point-free system, for any $i$, there is a divisor $E_i$ in $Q$ such that $E_i(p_i)=0$.

But now I'm stuck, I tried some combinations of the $E_i$'s to get the desired divisor, but I don't find it.

Remarks : I don't know much about sheaves and schemes, so I can't use it. And I'm very sorry for the notation above, I'm new to this site and I haven't figured out yet how to get nice notations.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be cheating but here goes, since $D$ is base point free $\dim L(D) < \dim L(D+p)$ for all $p$. You want to show that $L(D) \neq \cup_{i} L(D+p_i)$ but this should be obvious since a vector space cannot be the union of a finite number of spaces of smaller dimension.

Comment: I'm not really convinced that I want to show that, how do you get the union in there?

Comment: Wnat I mean to say, I am not sure I am using the right notation, but if you consider all divisors which contain $p$ (that is you add $p$ as a base point) then you get a system of lower dimension. The question is for a divisor which does not lie in a finite number of such subsystems. Whats the notation for adding $p$ as base point ? $D+p$ ?

Comment: I think I get what you mean, it seems like a useful idea.

Comment: I think I found a proof, thanks, I'm going to check it again tomorrow, I feel my head spinning today, I've been stuck on this for far too long.

Comment: If you have a different proof, please post it.

Comment: I used your idea: 

consider the linear system |D| and finitely many points p_1, ...,p_n. 

By the freeness, dim L(D-p_i)= dim L(D)+1. 
Write |D|={D+div(f) | f\in L(D)}.

Suppose that there is no E\in |D| such that it is zero on the p_i's.

Choose E\in |D|, write E = D +div(f), then for some i, E(p_i)>0, hence f\in L(D-p_i).

So |D|= {D+div(f) | f\in \cup_i L(D-p_i)}, so \cup_i L(D-p_i) = L(D), but this is impossible by the dimensions.